# Redmine: Find all issues ever assigned to me

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I need to list all redmine issues that I ever worked on, so all issues that have ever been assigned to me.
The filter does not give me a suitable option.
I reassigned most of these issues, so I could inspect the activity stream manually, which is too time consuming.
Thanks for any hint, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Which version of Redmine are you using?

Comment: So sorry, can't identify the version, since I am only frontend user, no admin priviledges.

Comment: Then you should ask your admin, and have him fix the plugin as well... There is also involvements plugin https://github.com/commandprompt/redmine_involvement_filter also check forks...

Answer (score 0):

To view all the issues you have to click on the "view all issues" link. The url should be: your-redmine-installation/issues

To filter by user, you have to select "Author" from the "Add filter" dropdown. Then select the user whoose issues you want to view.

Comment: Sorry, this gives me the issues that are currently assigned to me. What I want is a list of issues that in once in history have been assigned to me und in most cases are not any more. So to say, I want all issues that I have ever been involved in.

Comment: Well you can add another filter called "status". If you set it to any then it will show you all issues

Comment: Again, this does not give me a list of all issues that I have ever been involved in. Just a list of issues that are still assigned to me, but have any state (closed, open, new,...).